# Convert math expression into C or Java code

Tags: java, c, expression

I need to rewrite this expression into code (C or Java):

`g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `f`, `f0` are variables

**Expression**:

```
val = 1/{g+h[ln(f0/f)]+i[ln^2(f0/f)]+j[ln^3(f0/f)]-273.15;
```

The problem I have is converting `ln^2(f0/f)` into code.

Is this `(pow(ln(fo/f),2))` and `ln^3(f0/f)` is `pow(ln(f0/f),3)`?

Thank you.

Comment: The natural logarithm is `log(x)` instead of `ln(x)` in C

Comment: adding `#include <math.h>` and adding `libm`.

Comment: Does the expression not have ending brace anywhere?

Comment: Yes my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double result =  1/(g + h*Math.log(f0/f) + i*Math.pow(Math.log(f0/f), 2) + j*Math.pow(Math.log(f0/f), 3) -273.15);
```

Comment: You've `f0/f0` in your code, which should be `f0/f`

Answer (score 3):

Translating the expression:

```
val = 1 / { g + h[ ln(f0 / f) ] + i[ ln^2(f0 / f) ] + j[ ln^3(f0 / f) ] - 273.15}
```

**Java**:

In Java, [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class provides different methods for mathematical operations:

```
double logRes = Math.log(f0 / f); // As ln(f0/f) is been used more than once, so it's
// better to have it calculated just once.
double result = 1.0 / (g + (h * logRes) + (i * Math.pow(logRes, 2.0)) + (j * Math.pow(logRes, 3.0)) - 273.15);
```

**C**:

In C, [`math.h`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm) provides different functions to perform mathematical operations:

```
double logRes = log(f0 / f);
double result = 1.0 / (g + (h * logRes) + (i * pow(logRes, 2.0)) + (j * pow(logRes, 3.0)) - 273.15);
```

Answer (score 1):

In java, `ln^n(f0/f)` would be: `Math.pow(Math.log(f0/f), n)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the ready-at-your-fingertips built-in Math functions in Java, you can turn to the javadoc for [java.lang.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

There you can find [log(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log(double)) for example.